# Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 throws error: Windows has stopped this device because it reported problems (code 43)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics, hp-spectre

I own a HP Spectre 13 2016 (Model Number: Y4G37PA#AB5) running on Windows 10 Home Version 1903 64-Bit. Recently I noticed that the brightness functionality of my computer does not seem to work. When the buttons are clicked, nothing is displayed on the screen, nor is the brightness changed. The Windows notification panel has also disabled the brightness slider.

I checked the Device Manager and have noticed an error being thrown by Intel(R) HD Graphics 520. I have no other display adaptors installed. When I click the properties of the Intel(R) HD Graphics 520, it shows the following error in the `Device Status`:

`Windows has stopped this device because it reported problems (code 43)`

When I launch the `DirectX Diagnostic Tool` using `dxdiag` command from the Start Menu, I can see under `Display > Device` it is written `Microsoft Basic Display Driver`, with the following error in notes:

`There is a problem with the Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 device. For more information search for "graphic device driver error code 43"`. Following this search prompt, I have tried the following:

1. Uninstalling the display driver by Right Clicking Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 in device Manger: The result of this was the computer restarting and then completely glitching out with a black screen.
2. Updating the Driver By right clicking and searching automatically: The result was the message `Best driver for your device are already installed`.

I am hoping that you could help us resolve the Error Code 43. So that the computer can use the Intel HD Graphics 520 device.

Thank you.

Comment: Download, install and run the Intel driver assistant, see if it finds a newer driver for the 520 device and install it.......https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28425/Intel-Driver-Support-Assistant

Comment: We have also tried doing that. It claims `Your Intel software is up to date`. And our problem is still not solved.